# updating d3 data using intervals

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, setinterval, nvd3.js

Im new to D3. i'm trying to update my data every 5 secs using an setInterval to update my data array. I want to only run the interval on the data and not my entire D3 code. Also I only want to append the newly added index to the data once the interval has ran, while keeping the previously added interval data on the chart. A Fiddle would be great. Thanks

```
//DATA//
    $scope.reg = data;
    var rate  = parseInt($scope.reg);
         var bardata=[];
      setInterval(function(){
    bardata.push(rate);
    console.log("REG", $scope.reg, bardata);
    }, 5000);

//D3//
                var height = 500,
                        width = 600,
                        barwidth = 50,
                        barOffset = 5
              d3.select('#showResponder').append('svg')
                      .attr('width', width)
                      .attr('height', height)
                      .style('background', 'lightgrey')

                      .selectAll('rect').data(bardata) //this needs to update every 5 secs
                      .enter().append('rect')
                      .style('fill','black')
                      .attr('width', barwidth)
                      .attr('height', function(d){return d;})

                .attr('x', function(d,i){
                    return i *(barwidth + barOffset)
                })

                .attr('y', function(d){
                    return height - d;
                })
```

Answer (score 2):

You do want to run your d3 code every time you update your data, just not all of it. You have some d3 setup code that should run at the beginning, and some update code that gets the d3 elements to look the correct way.

Notice how there is some code that needs to run at the start. Then, the update code handles changing the data and styling the entering elements. You just call the update with your new data to get it to update properly.

```
// Setup code
var height = 500,
    width = 600,
    barwidth = 50,
    barOffset = 5
var container = d3.select('#showResponder').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .style('background', 'lightgrey')

var rects = container.selectAll('rect').data(bardata)

// Update code
function updateData(data) {
    rects = rects.data(bardata)
    rects.enter().append('rect')
        .style('fill','black')
        .attr('width', barwidth)
        .attr('height', function(d){return d;})
        .attr('x', function(d,i){
            return i *(barwidth + barOffset)
        })
        .attr('y', function(d){
            return height - d;
        })
}

// Data source
$scope.reg = data;
var rate  = parseInt($scope.reg);
var bardata=[];
setInterval(function(){
    bardata.push(rate);
    updateData(bardata)
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I see, but when running this code im getting an error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: NM i fixed that just getting a new error where saying: 
Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute